# How do I get a Canon 8600F Scanner working?

Tags: canon, scanner

Several years now I have been unable to get my Canon 8600F scanner working in Ubuntu. Does anyone know of a way to make this work?

There is another very similar scanner that is fully supported (the 8800F). Is there any way to hack that particular driver to use with my 8600?

Thanks for any tips or tricks!

http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON

Answer (score 2):

From the SANE web-page - the 8800 and 8600 versions are in-fact very different even if they are similarly named.

The 8600F is a GL841 based scanner.

The 8800F is basically a PIXMA based scanner.

Thus, to answer your question directly - since they are quite different scanners, the 8600 driver cannot be "tweaked" to use the 8800F driver.

So - unless someone picks up the challenge (or Canon themselves start supporting this scanner), your scanner will not work under linux.